# export function with [ or [[ by using roxygen

Tags: r, devtools, roxygen2

Which is the correct method to export a function with `[`?

A MWE of what I want to do would be

```r
myfun <- function(x) {
    stopifnot(is.numeric(x))
    y <- x^2
    class(y) <- c("numeric", "myfun")
    return(y)
}

`[[.myfun` <- function(z,i) {
    return(1/z[i])
}

a <- myfun(1:5)
a[2] # 4
a[[2]] # 1/4
```

This is based on [What are these square brackets for S3 classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49744397/what-are-these-square-brackets-for-s3-classes) but when decorate with `#' @exportS3Method` and use `devtools::document()`, then I get an error

```
Error in parse(con, keep.source = FALSE, srcfile = NULL) : 
  5:10: unexpected '['
5: S3method([
```

Comment: Just use `#' @export`. Where exactly are you putting that line in your function. You only use `@exportS3Method` when reexporting methods from suggested packages; not when defining your own methods.

Comment: Sir, you are a genius. @export created `S3method("[",myfun)` in NAMESPACE